# Why isn't target data updated after changing glue job scripte?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have defined a `glue job` to transform data from s3 source bucket to s3 target bucket. The script I am using in the job is `Python`. It works fine and loads many data to the target bucket. But later I changed the schema by updating python script to drop a field (`edited`):

```
applymapping1 = applymapping1.drop_fields(['edited'])
```

After re-run the job, the new data arrived on the s3 source bucket followed the new scheme but the old data on the target bucket is not updated. How can I let `glue` job to run against the existing data on the target bucket? Do I have to delete the bucket and re-run the job again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glue doesn't overwrite target data. It always appends new files ([some collisions may happen though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061213/glue-job-fails-to-write-file/57078141#57078141)). So if output schema is changed then you need to delete old data files and re-run a job to generate new ones.

Alternatively, you can [overwrite data using Spark's native 'write' function in your Glue job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001781/overwrite-parquet-files-from-dynamic-frame-in-aws-glue/52013288#52013288).